# Prove matrix identity involving null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions

Let $A \in \mathsf{M}_n$ and suppose that $ \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. Prove that $ E_\lambda = \mathsf{N}(\lambda I_n - A)$.

$N$ stands for the null space, $I_n$ stands for the n x n identity matrix, and $E_\lambda$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect by $E_\lambda$ you mean the eigenspace of $\lambda$, which can be described by
$$
E_\lambda :=\{x \mid x=0\ \text{or}\ x\ \text{is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$}\}
= \{x \mid Ax=\lambda x\}.
$$

Then $x\in E_\lambda$ iff $Ax=\lambda x$ iff
$$
0=\lambda x-Ax=\lambda I_nx-Ax = (\lambda I_n-A)x
$$
iff $x$ is in the null space of $\lambda I_n-A$.
Therefore $E_\lambda = \mathsf{N}(\lambda I_n-A)$.

Comment: this is sort of irreverent but i was wondering if i should also prove it in the reverse as the question is asking to proving equals. Do i need to?

Comment: @LKRC The "iff" stands for "if and only if", which means that it is handling both directions simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
  E_\lambda
  &= \{x : Ax=\lambda x\} \\
  &= \{x : \lambda x- Ax=\mathbf{0}\} \\
  &= \{x : (\lambda\cdot I-A)x=\mathbf{0}\} \\
  &= \mathsf{N}(\lambda\cdot I-A)
\end{align*}